# What happens if I have several overlapping QTimer

Tags: c++, qt, overlapping, qtimer

Suppose I have 2 `QTimer` objects with **10, 20** as their **intervals**. And suppose I want to run `slot1()` with timer 1 `timeout` signal and `slot2` with timer 2. So running order of `slot1` and `slot2` is something like this :

```
10ms-----20ms-----------30ms----40ms-----  
(slot1) (slot1, slot2) (slot1) (slot1, slot2)...
```

I want to know after 20 milliseconds which one of `slot1` & `slot2` executes at first? and how can I force the event loop to run `slot2` and then `slot1` when they have overlap.(`slot2` is more important for me to run on time)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no guarantee that slots in two timers get called with specific orders. This is because you are starting them in different times and also `QTimer` at best has millisecond accuracy by setting this :

```
timer.setTimerType(Qt::PreciseTimer);
```

The default is `Qt::CoarseTimer`  which causes to have an accuracy within 5% of the desired interval.

About your case, if you want to call `slot2` and `slot1` in order you can call them in a slot connected to a timer with interval of 10 :

```
void myClass::onTriggered()
{
    if(count % 2==0)
        slot2();
    slot1();

    count++;
}
```